# push notification through desktop application and azure

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have a desktop application with a button. When I press the button, a push notification should go on desktop and on the mobile phone simultaneously. We have to use Azure as a service. Can anybody help me out with the basic framework.

Comment: You have to provide where you're stuck exactly. If you haven't tried at all, this is not the place to ask.

Comment: see i dont know how to associate my desktop application click button to the azure web service.

Comment: You could try to read [Azure Notification Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-overview).